# Questions about complexes and homology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I just learn about the simplicial and delta complexes and computing homology group. But I have a few questions:

1. Is there any topological space which cannot be given a delta compplex structure?
2. Is delta complex and simplicial complex of a space (eg. torus) homeomorphic?
3. Does different triangulation give a different homology?
4. Can I give a delta complex structure for torus like the picture below? I know it is not minimal, but is there a rule for the triangulation?

[image]

Any explanation is appreciated :)

Comment: I feel like all of these questions are answered in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*. Have you tried reading the section on homology in that freely available text?

Comment: For 1.: Yes take something non-Haussdorf for example the line with two origins. 3) No 4) Yes, no

Comment: @DanRust these questions come up after I read Hatcher. He did not give proper answer or may be put it somewhere in the next section.

Comment: @ThomasRot, Thanks so much for the answer, now I have a deeper understanding. Thanks :)